# How save Facebook user display picture to the disk or use it without saving?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am trying to get the user profile picture and then merge into an existing image as per my Facebook app requirement. But I am having difficulty in retrieving and assigning the picture to ‘imagecreatefromjpeg()’ function.

I need help regarding this, how do achieve this. If it’s necessary to save the picture first and then merge, then how can I save the pic from the fb graph link to disk? Kindly help.

```
$userPicture = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId) -> picture;
        $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId -> picture;
        file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($userPicture);
        //$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $userId . "/picture?type=large");
        $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

        imagecopymerge($dest, $src, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
        imagejpeg($dest, 'fImage.jpg');
        imagedestroy($dest);
        imagedestroy($src);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixing too many things up, it should be really simple:

```
$url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$userId}/picture";

// You may download the image first
$img = 'my_facebook_image.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
// And work with downloaded one
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);

// Or you may use it directly if the fopen wrappers have been enabled
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

// Do whatever you want with an image resource...
```

Comment: Thankyou.
But while am trying to access it directly it is giving me this warning.

`Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error`

`Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'http://graph.facebook.com/100003482890169/picture' is not a valid JPEG file`

How ever when am saving the file it is saving it as a .jpg file?

Comment: This is due to fact that this user doesn't have image and default placeholder images for users are GIF instead of JPEG. It's probably good idea to download the image and check it's mime before processing...